# How to retrieve the values in the array after comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my JavaScript:

```
let test = [
  {
    name : 'doe',
    age : 8
  },
  {
    name : 'john',
    age : 17
  }
],
console.log(test.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.age > acc ? curr.age : acc, 0))
```

I did a comparison with age, but I want the result to be a name (`John`). if I console `curr.name` the result is `doe`. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the entire object in the accumulator and use destructuring assignment.

```js
let test = [
  {
    name : 'doe',
    age : 8
  },
  {
    name : 'john',
    age : 17
  }
];
let {name} = test.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.age > acc.age ? curr : acc, {age: 0});
console.log(name);
```

Comment: @dediwibisono No problem.

Comment: hi, there's a small issue, for example I added one more object with the same age {'name': 'steve', 'age': 17}. Could you please show [John, steve]. because at the moment I'm trying to only show John @iota

Comment: @dediwibisono You may want to ask a new question in that case.